# How do I include my Android hash in an Authy message?

Tags: android, twilio, authy

I am trying to use the Android `[SMSRetriever][1]` API to auto-read a token sent using Authy. However, I am unable to find out how to include a custom string (in this case, my app's Android hash) in the text that Authy will send.

Is this a matter of an extra request parameter to be sent to Authy, or something I need to set up on the dashboard in Twilio? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe that if you include the parameters `action` and `action_message` you can set the message sent as an SMS [when you request a token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/one-time-passwords#request-a-one-time-password). Note that you need to set the action to the same when you verify the token too.